# how to delete single character from entry widget tkinter?

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm trying to delete a character from entry widget with `.delete()` method.

```
def efface():
      MAIN_txt.config(state=NORMAL)
      MAIN_txt.delete(0,)
      MAIN_txt.config(state="readonly")
```

The problem is I want it to delete the last character first, not the first one.
I have tried `MAIN_txt(0,END)` and `MAIN_txt(END,)` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# delete the last character
MAIN_txt.delete(len(MAIN_txt.get())-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that @novel 's method does not work.

the correct method is as follows:

```
MAIN_txt.delete((len(MAIN_txt.get()-1))
```

At first it might seem that both answers are same, but in novels answer
he had missed the brackets for the `len(MAIN_txt.get()-1` this will make a error..

hopes this is helpful to someone even after 3 years